# html fitting a text in a table-cell to an image in a different table-cell

Tags: jquery, html, css

If you like to see what I'm about to describe - the example is in:
http://www.letsfeedme.com/moments?moment_id=555900f35c7255bb6f8b4ab3
(The text that starts with - `I love events like these...`)

TL-DR: Text height should be fitted by the space generated by the image in the other column (but not pass it - the image should set the height of both columns)

Explanation:

I have 2 divs I want in an equal height, that will be decided by the image (if the image is high, we have lots of room for text, if it is low, the text should have a scroller like it is right now)

Currently I'm using `display:table` for the container and `display:table-cell` for the columns.

The text height is set to a % of the column width - in a js code (so it won't be bigger than the image) but it doesn't take into consideration the image height.

I tried calculating the height is jQuery (I'm cool with jQuery/js solutions) but the `.parent().parent().height()` is giving me the wrong number, I understood that it is because it doesn't know the height of the image.

I like that the image is 100% width and I don't need to do fancy calculations, so having the img tag get the "right" dimensions is not an option I like

Any ideas how I can fix it?

Comment: What prevents you from simply removing `height` from `.chapter-text`?

Comment: If there is a lot of text, I don't want it to go over the image height (and make a white gap under the image - because the text side is higher)

Answer (score 0):

What I eventually did was to provide a `data-original-img-width` and `data-original-img-height` to the div, and do the calculation in jQuery once I know the width.

Would still love to hear other solutions